# how to change bg color in real time in dependence of serial read?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyserial

this is my first GUI
[image]

and I want to change bg color of Buttons in real time.
maybe smothing like this, but I am not sure where to put it.. :(

```
 b = ser.read()
 
    if b == b'1': 
        start_forButton.configure(bg='red') 
    else:
        start_forButton.configure(bg='white')

    if b == b'2':  
        start_backButton.configure(bg='red')  
    else:
        start_backButton.configure(bg='white')
```

[image]

maybe with after function, becouse code that I have now is changing color but with one clik delay, not in real time.

Comment: how does `ser.read()` work? Does it block, or will it return a value immediately?

Comment: You have to say what `b` is and `b'1'` too along with what `ser.read()` will do

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command in the button widget to call a function to change colors...

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def move_forward_pressed():
    button1.configure(bg='red')
def stop_pressed():
    button1.configure(bg='green')

button1 = Button(root, text='move forward', bg='green', command=move_forward_pressed)
button1.pack()
button2 = Button(root, text='stop', command=stop_pressed)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, I added ser.flusInput after ser.read commmand, and StartLogger so that the porogram reads serial port every 100ms.

Now Buttons are changing bg color in real time (with delay 100ms):

```
  def warning():
         b = ser.read()
         ser.flushInput()
         print(b)

         if b == b'1': 
         start_forButton.configure(bg='red')  

         if b == b'2': 
         start_backButton.configure(bg='red')  
         
         if b==b'0':
         start_forButton.configure(bg='white')
         start_backButton.configure(bg='white')

    def startLogger():
             while True:
                 warning()
                 sleep(0.1)
```